# Reactivecocoa 3.0 Release Candidate 1 With Project targeting iOS 7

Tags: swift, ios7, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I have a iOS project Which support iOS-7 and later (The project is written by Swift), I use with Reactivecocoa Version 2.5 (via Cocoa-pods). I want to upgrade to the new Reactivecoca RC version.

I know embedded frameworks require a minimum deployment target of iOS 8 or OS X Mavericks.

How can I use Reactivecocoa Release Candidate 1 with a project targeting iOS 7.
I try to include all Swift files located inside the Source directory in my project, But without success. (It works for me with Alamofire).
I also try to add the Reactivecocoa Release Candidate with Git submodule.

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question there:

> I know embedded frameworks require a minimum deployment target of iOS 8 or OS X Mavericks.

So its not going to work on iOS7.

Also according to the guys who's developer the library:  https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa

> ReactiveCocoa supports OS X 10.9+ and iOS 8.0+.

There is no way to get it to work on iOS7. My suggestion is to change your development target to iOS8 +